# How to place a perfect curve to join two circles together?

Tags: vector

I have two circles in this position

[image]

I'm looking to acheive this (but more perfect with the flow of the curve meeting the circle perfectly on the right) notice, that it is slightly off)

[image]

How would I be able to do this that the three curves when whole are perfect circles?

[image]

I am using Corel Draw, but can also do this in Illustrator.

Sizes of the circles and positioning

[image]

Comment: In your picture with the 3 circles, why not trace over the connecting curve with the pen tool?

Comment: Why is a circle connecting perfect? I mean its only a C1 continuous connection, C2 is easily attainable and surely more perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Measure the radi/diameters of your circles.

1. Decide on a radius(diameter for the connecting curve, the higher this value the less curved the connection is.
2. Draw a circle with the desired diameter + the diameter (or 2 * radius) of the upper circle, centered on the upper circle center.
3. Draw a circle with the desired diameter - the diameter (or 2 * radius) of the lower circle, centered on the lower circle center.

   [image]
4. The center of the new circle is at the intersection point of these 2 circles with the radius you decided in step 1.

   [image]

Comment: a triumph of intuitive math.

Comment: @user287001 Geometry is intuitive if you have insight into it. But its a bit problematic to use effectively. I have 30 years of geometry studies behind me so what is self eveident to me is not necceserily self exident to everybody. You may wish to see [this lecture's start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0eJXttPRZI) Where the limitation is explained well.

Comment: Good to note: the desired radius should be at least larger than `d - 2*r1 - 2*r2`, where `d` is the distance between the centers of the two circles. Otherwise the connecting curve is not able to connect the two circles.